# Obfuscating Email Addresses in Form Fields

Tags: email, forms, contact

I'm writing a WP Theme where registered users can email post authors sending them en email from the post's page itself.

So I created a contact form in which I get the user and author infos and emails and I put them in hidden input fields to pass them to the php mail function.

Does WordPress have a way to obfuscate the post author's email address, to protect it from scrapers? Is there a better way to implement this functionality, other than outputting the author email address in the form field?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you take a look into the very easy to use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ instead of reinventing the wheel, although I don't know what you're really aiming for without looking at it. Perhaps you can provide a link?

Comment: As-written, this really isn't a **WordPress** -related question.

Comment: @Chip Bennet As there's a template tag/core function for that, it's imo valid and wp related.

Comment: @kaiser **as-written**, this question asks about HTML form fields, putting email addresses into hidden form fields, and using the PHP mail function. It *could* be written in a way that is **WordPress** related, but it isn't currently.

Comment: I've attempted a re-write, to make the question more WordPress-specific.

Comment: @Chip Bennet I guess it's ok to edit a Q to make it fitting. Haven't found another one where obfuscating via core was asked. The current edit imo extends our Q/A format in best manner.

Comment: @kaiser that's what I'm after: making questions better, thereby soliciting better/more useful answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core function to obfuscate mail addresses:

```
antispambot( $emailaddy, $mailto );
```

Second arg is 0 or 1 and optional.

Comment: Oh! Is *this* what the OP was asking? Okay, let me attempt an edit to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I guess so. I already deleted my answer containing info about the `wp_mail()` function as I missunderstood it in the first place.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to discuss `wp_mail()`, I can delete mine. :)

Comment: No. It's ok to have different answers to cover the whole topic :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Question was not clear enought because I didn't know if WP had built-in ways to solve the problem, but antispambot sure will do!

Answer (score 0):

You could alternately use [the `wp_mail()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) to send the commenter's email on form submission. That way, the post author's email address never has to be exposed publicly in the form field to begin with.